# Write UnitTests for Internal Class of a library

Tags: c#, mstest, microsoft-fakes

I have the below class in the library i have to write UnitTests for and was given by my dev team to write unit tests for it.

```
internal sealed class Settings : AppSettingsBase
{
    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default { get { return defaultInstance; } }
}
```

Since its internal i couldn't access it in my .Tests project. When i looked in the stackoverflow the suggestion was to ask the developer to put an attribute [assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyTests")] in the AssemblyInfo.cs file. This is what i am going to request my developer but its going to take some time.

Is there a way to do it through any reflection concept or any other concept to read those properties or variables. I am using Microsoft FAkes in my test project.

Comment: why cant you add the assembly attribute? why would it take him forever/some time to do when it Is literally a one liner?

Comment: Before unit testing this class, what are you even going to test there? It seems there is nothing in the class to test.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of unit tests is to test publicly accessible aspects of the code. As it's internal, it shouldn't be directly unit tested. Test the public functionality that uses this class instead.

If you must test it, then the solution is indeed to add `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyTests")]` to the assembly. This doesn't take long. It simply requires a quick edit to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

Comment: As far as I know this is the purpose of integration tests. Unit tests should test small units like classes / methods and mock everything.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia, that's a common misconception over what a "unit" is when unit testing. A unit is a single, repeatable, aspect of the functionality that ought to have no side affects and thus can be run in any order and in parallel. See http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/ for details. Integration tests come into play when side affects result from the test, which means they need careful set up, tear down and scheduling.

Comment: Oh and @IgnacioSolerGarcia, mocking only needs to occur if the code under test has side affects. Good code, that uses lots of pure functions and minimal state needs no mocking. State is often necessary though and in those cases, the stateful functionality needs to be mocked in a unit test, but not in an integration test.

Comment: Well, pure functions and minimal state sounds like functional programming to me (F#) rather than C#. I have read the book and I really disagree with several parts of it. About this one ... I'm still unsure. Thanks for the explanation anyway!